# Fetching the Right corresponding value from sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, textview, android-sqlite

I am developing a small app in which am inserting two values into the database(Phone Number and Address).
Am done with the insertion part. Now I would like to search for a corresponding address to a particular phone number. I have followed a tutorial from **Androidhive** and it has worked out fairly well. My problem is when I insert a particular phone number(which is already stored in the database) and hit search button, My `TextView` is not displaying the corresponding address. It just displays "name" in that text. Am preety sure i have not hardcoded the text "name" anywhere. And am not getting any particular error as well.

Here is the code for my buttonSearch:

```
buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                long phone_number=Long.parseLong(searchEditText.getText().toString());

            String text=db.getAddress(phone_number);
            fetchedAddressTextView.setText(text);
            }
```

And this is the `getAddress` method defined in my Helper class:

```
public String getAddress(long phone_number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


        try {
            Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{
                    KEY_ADDRESS
            },
            KEY_PH_NO + "=" + phone_number,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
            }
        }
            catch (Exception e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return KEY_ADDRESS;
    }
```

`KEY_ADDRESS` should return the address corresponding to the number I searched for in form of a string.

So any help with this problem is appreciated. Or any other pointers regarding simple fetching of stored values in the database(other then vogella or androidhive)are welcome.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is returning column name instead of value. Please check below code after c.moveToFirst(); statement

```
public String getAddress(long phone_number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();


        try {
            Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{
                    KEY_ADDRESS
            },
            KEY_PH_NO + "=" + phone_number,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                return c.getString (c.getColumnIndex (KEY_ADDRESS));
            }
        }
            catch (Exception e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return "";
    }
```